# menu with <select> inside <div> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am building a menu. On button hover I would like to expose the child div and be able to use the select with options. However when I click on the dropdown the div is hidden. What am I doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cronwall/6E5j8/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="myButton">Hover me!
    <div id="menuBox">
        <label for="m1">Choose me!</label>
        <select id="m1">
            <option value="high">High</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="m2">Or me!</label>
        <select id="m2">
            <option value="high">High</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="m3">Also me!</label>
        <select id=m3>
            <option value="high">High</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#myButton")
    .hover(function () {
    $(this).children().toggle().position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        of: this
    });
})
   .children().hide();
```

**CSS**

```
#myButton {
    height:20px;
    background:red;
    float:left
}
#menuBox {
    background:blue;
    height:100px;

}
label,select{
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    }
select{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work correctly for me on Chrome 35

Comment: I just tested on other systems than my regular linux machine. It works on Win-Chrome and Mac-Chrome but not Chromium or Firefox on Linux

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="myButton">Hover me!
    <div id="menuBox">
        <label for="m1">Choose me!</label>
        <select id="m1">
            <option value="high">High</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="m2">Or me!</label>
        <select id="m2">
            <option value="high">High</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label for="m3">Also me!</label>
        <select id=m3>
            <option value="high">High</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
   #myButton {
    height:20px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}
#myButton:hover #menuBox
{
   display: block;
}
#menuBox {
    background:blue;
    height:100px;
    display: none;
}
label,select{
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
    }
select{
    float:right;
}

</style>
```

no need to use js for this you can make this only by using css pls try this code

Comment: This is a more elegant solution, thank you. However I can still reproduce the issue in Chrome 35 on Ubuntu 12.04. No other browser I tested produce the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue on `firefox v29.0.1` and tuned your code a bit, id this what you wanted

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
         var stopBit = false;
         $("#myButton")
             .hover(function () {
            if (stopBit) {
                 stopBit = false;
                 return false;
            }
            $(this).children().toggle().position({
              my: "left top",
              at: "left bottom",
              of: this
            });
         });
         .children().hide();

       $('select').on('click', function () {
              stopBit = true
       });
```

**LIVE DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/6E5j8/5/

Happy Coding :)